# How is argv passed to the new process image with execvp()?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, process, system-calls

The man page does not seem to specify how this is done. I am confused particularly because of this line from [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fexecve.html): `The argv[] and envp[] arrays of pointers and the strings to which those arrays point shall not be modified by a call to one of the exec functions, except as a consequence of replacing the process image.`

Are the argument arrays copied somewhere before the process image is replaced? That line seems to imply that they are always modified because the process image is always replaced.

I see that the document also says the following: `The statement about argv[] and envp[] being constants is included to make explicit to future writers of language bindings that these objects are completely constant.`

I feel like this could help my understanding but I'm not entirely sure exactly what they are saying is constant here.

In addition I would like to know why it is good or bad to cast the constant `c_str()` from `std::string` to pass to `execvp()` in the `argv`.

Thanks.

Comment: `exec()` functions can fail as well as succeed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec()` functions can fail, and return an error indication. This occurs in the calling process, and the calling process continues to run. In this case, `exec()` simply fails, just like any other system call, like `open()` or `read()` can fail. It's just a failed system call.

All that what you quoted means is that in this event the strings that were passed into `exec()` do not get modified. Upon return from `exec()` their content remains unaltered by the `exec()` call itself.

> That line seems to imply that they are always modified because the process
> image is always replaced

No, the process image is not always replaced. If you pass in a pathname to `exec()` which does not exist, it should be apparent that it can't possibly be replaced by anything, and an error gets returned.

Comment: Is it known or on a per implementation basis whether the arguments are copied somewhere for the new process image or referenced in place?

Comment: This is not specified by the C++ standard. However, as a practical matter, the operating system does whatever is needed so that the arguments become ordinary strings in a new process. We have to deduce that something somewhere gets copied, since it is extremely unlikely that the strings' addresses in the new process would be identical to the old process's. The new process is an entirely new operating system process, that is likely occupying entirely different memory pages. How do you get from there to here without copying anything?

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but if after a `fork()` the new process called `exec()`, passed in arguments, and the new process attempted to modify those arguments, it would not trigger a copy on write? Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: Probably not, but there is no universal answer to this which is the same for every operating system in the world.